# CSS horizontal or vertical line less than height or width of div

Tags: css

I have two divs of the same height vertically aligned, side by side with each other. As a visual separator between them, I want to have a 3px wide rectangular bar which is almost the height of the divs, vertically centred with them, floating so that there's about 10px top and bottom not covered by the divider.

I also want to do a similar thing for horizontal divs.

An quick photoshop mockup of what I want to do (blue outlines are approx locations of divs, blue text are descriptions of the divs)
Grey lines are where I want the dividers to be for 3 divs:

http://imageshack.us/a/img821/9444/divs.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this. Adjust the values to your liking. Right now I made them a percentage.

http://jsfiddle.net/frexuz/3CSde/1/